# Questions for Context in Android. How does it work and why?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out what is the use of the context when it is being passed back into the constructor in an example below , can anyone help to give a more layman explanation and its possible use ? Thank you !

```
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

        this.myContext = context;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Context contains all information about your application, and I believe it's used here to prevent your application access all databases but yours. That's why we need the Context...

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! Would you be a little bit more explanatory about it? I'm quite lost about it .... thanks!

Comment: Well, Context [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is a system environment in android apps, it's used to work with DBs, media collection, UI, etc. It's to divide apps from each other and to provide set of rules of their communication, some kind of a protocol (Intent). Your app without the Context is just a java program that can only exit(0); and nothing else )))